# Socket.io: Node.js can't receive event message via method socket.on('message', ...) on AWS

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm having this problem even with [the Socket.io official chat sample](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/).

I had this set up on AWS. I could only received the 'successfully connected' message on the terminal but not the 'message: ....'. Even with Google Dev Tool I couldn't saw any related error. Anyone could help?

Here's the client side javascript code:

```
  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.4.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script>
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(){
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
  </script>
```

Then the server side node.js code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});
http.listen(8989, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:8989');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('successfully connected');
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});
```

Comment: @michael Thanks for the info, but after testing the way using http.listen(8989, ....) like above is good except there's the io.connect() needed as mentioned in my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the problem was on the client side javascript code.

I referred to [this sample code](http://pastebin.com/8dBiNnBT) and found that on socket.io official website it says in some cases (Express 3/4 or the framework) you need to use io.connect() instead of io(). However it works for me in my previous case.

Here's the changed code:

```
var socket = io.connect();
$('form').submit(function(){
  socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
  $('#m').val('');
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no form submit on button click, also form submit will create a lot of page refreshes and everything, and also you dont need a form for this exercise

Create a function `sendMessage()`

```
<script>
    var socket = io();
    function sendMessage(){
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
    }
</script>
```

In your HTML remove form and add onclick to button

```
<body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @joyBlanks, but the problem isn't on the HTML side.